# Issue using bootstrap responsive for tablet and phones

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am designing a page using bootstrap responsive for the following image and I'm beginner for using bootstrap responsive..[image: create_account.png for create_account page]

And the html is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap Responsive</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="description">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<style>
    .container {
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    #main-form {
        margin: auto;
        width:  500px;
    }
    .profile-photo {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .form {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .profile-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <img src="img/slider/1.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" />
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h2>Create your account</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="main-form">
                <div class="span2">
                    <div class="profile-photo">
                        <img class="profile-image" src="img/slider/1.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3 form">
                      <div class="widget-container widget-box4">  
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    </script>
</body>
```

I wanted it in the middle of the page and I'm getting correctly in Desktop.

But problem is the form and profile image are not coming in center.

Please help me how to do that?.

The work is more appreciated.

Comment: can you please post the test page .. ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done changes to your code please note that for phone layout maybe less than 500px which you have mentioned one of your container so your layout will be disturbed for phone, try use custom media queries for it, as far as html structure look at the changes...

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <img src="img/slider/1.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" />
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h2>Create your account</h2>
        </div>
            <div id="main-form" class="row">
                <div class="span5">
                    <div class="profile-photo">
                        <img class="profile-image" src="img/slider/1.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span7 form">
                      <div class="widget-container widget-box4">  
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    </script>
</body>
```